# How to access DQL query results from JOINS several levels deep?

Tags: doctrine-orm

I'm using DQL to do several joins like this:

```
SELECT m, c, ct, t FROM Message m 
JOIN m.classifications c 
LEFT JOIN c.current_translations ct 
LEFT JOIN ct.translation t
WHERE t.id IS NOT NULL
```

Once I get the results, how do I access the ct and t records?
I can access the c records through *$result->classifications* but where are the ct and t?

*$result->classifications[0]* doesn't have a current_translation property and *$result->current_translations* doesn't exist, I also tried *$result->ct* to no avail.

I know that the associations exist because of the WHERE clause.

How do I access my ct and t objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result is just a regular Entity, so:

```
$result->getClassifications()[0]->getCurrentTranslations()
```